# The system cannot find the file C:\play\bin\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt

```
ACTIVATOR_HOME=C:\play
The system cannot find the file `C:\play\bin\..\conf\sbtconfig.txt.
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

I'm facing this problem while installing the play framework.

I intalled sbt and Scala as referenced by one tutorial on the internet, but in vain.

My Java JDK is working properly and `sbtconfig.txt` file is not in play bin where above file is point to.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: "sorry for English" That's quite not a problem, the problem is punctuation... Take a breath!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do  not provide sbtconfig.txt then installer will throw warning but it will not stop. I have successfully installed play2 even after that message.

So please check that SBT_HOME and  ACTIVATOR_HOME  are correctly configured. But you got some other error like 'findstr' not found. So try both from creating a command shell and also by double clicking the batch file.  I hope that can solve the problem.

Comment: If that does not work you can remove this part of the activator.bat

Comment: rem Check what Java version is being used to determine what memory options to use
for /f "tokens=3" %%g in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /i "version"') do (
    set JAVA_VERSION=%%g
)

Comment: Also if findstr command is not found then you can try by adding C:\WINDOWS\system32 to PATH variable.

Comment: @Prebir Ghosh **thanks ** but it not working for me  'ACTIVATOR_HOME=c:\play\activator-dist-1.3.12
The system cannot find the file c:\play\activator-dist-1.3.12\bin.
'findstr' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.' this new error when i remove as u said

Comment: Did you try  by adding "C:\WINDOWS\system32" to PATH environment variable?   @ Asif  Qasim

Comment: @Prebir Ghosh thanks for your help it worked when i add path  environment variable